# If $A,B$ are Hermitian, how to show that $\lambda_\max(AB^{-1}) =\max_{x\ne 0} \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*Bx}$ if A,B have only positive eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, hermitian-matrices

If $A,B$ are Hermitian, how to show that $\lambda_\max(AB^{-1}) =\max_{x\ne 0} \frac{x^*Ax}{x^*Bx}$ if A,B have only positive eigenvalues? My idea is to use the Rayleigh theorem, but I don't know if $\lambda_{max}(AB^{-1})=\lambda_{max}A\lambda_{max}B^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick: if $B$ has only positive eigenvalues, then $B$ is invertible and has a positive square root $\sqrt{B}$ (satisfying $\sqrt{B}^2 = B$ with $\sqrt{B}$ also Hermitian, invertible, and with all positive eigenvalues). Then
\begin{equation*}
\max_{x \not = 0} \frac{x^* A x} {x^* B x}
= \max_{x \not = 0} \frac{x^* A x} {(\sqrt{B} x)^* (\sqrt{B} x)}
= \max_{x \not = 0} \frac{(\sqrt{B}^{-1} x)^* A (\sqrt{B}^{-1} x)} {x^* x}
= \max_{x \not = 0} \frac{x^* \sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x} {x^* x}.
\end{equation*}
Thus you can now apply the Rayleigh theorem to $A' := \sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1}$ and obtain that the the original expression $\max_{x \not = 0} \frac{x^* A x} {x^* B x}$ is equal to $\lambda_\text{max}(\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1})$.

It finally remains to check that the matrix $\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1}$ has the same eigenvalues as $A B^{-1}$. To see thus just note that we have the following chain of if-and-only-ifs:
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{\iff} \sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x = \lambda x\\
&\iff \forall y, (\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x, y) = (\lambda x, y)\\
&\iff \forall y, (A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x, \sqrt{B}^{-1} y) = (\lambda x, y)\\
&\iff \forall y, (A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x, y) = (\lambda x, \sqrt{B} y)\\
&\iff \forall y, (A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x, y) = (\lambda \sqrt{B} x,  y)\\
&\iff A \sqrt{B}^{-1} x = \lambda \sqrt{B} x \\
&\iff A \sqrt{B}^{-1} \sqrt{B}^{-1} (\sqrt{B} x) = \lambda (\sqrt{B} x) \\
&\iff A B^{-1} x = \lambda x.
\end{align*}
Thus (again since $\sqrt{B}$ is invertible) $x$ is an eigenvalue for $\sqrt{B}^{-1} A \sqrt{B}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ if and only if $\sqrt{B} x$ is an eigenvalue for $A B^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. This completes the proof.